# How do I include an integer in a string?

Tags: c++, string

If a system call fails, I would like to throw an exception that contains the 'errno' relating to the failure. Right now, I use this:

```
if (bind(...) == -1) {
   std::stringstream s;
   s << "Error:" << errno << " during bind";
   throw std::runtime_error(s.str());
}
```

That seems clumsy. I cannot directly append an integer to an std::string() - what is the best solution for this? Java has String().append(int), but there's no such facility in std::string. Does everyone write a wrapper around std::string for this purpose?

Comment: FYI, you could use [`strerror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/strerror.html) to convert an `errno` (and only `errno`'s) to a string

Comment: You were conflating two issues. You started out asking about how to raise exceptions, but then you said the real issue was how to put integers in strings, so I've edited your question to ask only about the real problem. Please post a separate question about how to conveniently throw exceptions with error information attached if you still want to know about that; it's a separate issue from string formatting.

Comment: If you do this a lot, a wrapper definitely makes sense.

Comment: Don't you also need to retrieve the error value?

Comment: @RobKennedy Thanks for the edit.

Everyone, thanks for the strerror mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::lexical_cast` is useful in this scenario:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Error:" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(errno) + " during bind");
```

Comment: or `throw runtime_error("Error: " + std::to_string(errno));` (C++11)

Answer (score 3):

I like using `boost::format` for this.

```
std::string msg = boost::str( boost::format("Error: %1% during bind") % errno );
throw std::runtime_error(msg);
```

One caveat is that if you have a `bad_alloc` in a catch block, you might hide the previous error.  `boost::format` uses allocations as far as I know, so it could suffer from this.  You aren't catching here, so it doesn't exactly apply.  It is something to be aware of with error handling though.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own:

Here is some hints:

```
class Exception{
public:
    Exception(const char* sourceFile, const char* sourceFunction, int sourceLine, Type type, const char* info = 0, ...);
protected:
    const char *mSourceFile;
    const char *mSourceFunction;
    int mSourceLine;
    Type mType;
    char mInfo[2048];
};
```

Where type could be:

```
enum Type
{
    UNSPECIFIED_ERROR,              //! Error cause unspecified.
    .. other types of error...  
};
```

So you can pass string in the usual format.. e.g.

```
Exception(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, Type::UNSPECIFIED_ERROR, "Error %d", myInt);
```